# Android-Jetpack-Compose @Composable annotation Error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

It works when I use the following code

```
setContent {
        TakisukazeTheme {
            Scaffold{
                Text(text = "测试")
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I use the following methods, there will be an error
Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation

```
setContent {
        TakisukazeTheme {
            AngleBtSetting()
        }
    }

@Composable
fun AngleBtSetting(){
    Scaffold(){
       Text(text = "测试")
    }
}
```

I don't know what caused this error

Comment: please add whole activity code

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the answer to the question because I imported the wrong package

In the right case I should import

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
```

However, I imported it by mistake

```
import androidx.compose.Composable
```